# да ладно meaning

Tags: этимология

I'm new to Russian language and I was wondering since Literal translation of да ладно doesn't mean "are you kidding" or "no way", I guess it should have some sort of irony like "no shit".
Could anyone explain the correct approach toward this meaning?

Comment: «"no shit" - Not at all» — Yes: «Да ладно!» it's more likely as «shit no»:)

Comment: Тематика форума не соответствует подобным вопросам.  Желательно, чтобы русский сленг объясняли носители английского языка, хорошо адаптированные в русскоязычной среде (а это не наш вариант).  Или  хотя бы приводили примеры из соответствующих литературных источников и словарей. В противном случае  истинность приводимых соответствий  сложно проверить.  Также должно быть соблюдено соответствие стилей. Вопрос подходит для другого форума, и об этом уже говорилось.

Comment: «(а это не наш вариант)» — who are these «you» to whom this option does not apply?:)

Comment: Sharon, "Желательно, чтобы русский сленг объясняли носители английского языка," - что вы вообще городите ? :>

Comment: in this case a full version will : да ладно тебе врать , f.e. ; - stop your lie. "да ладно" here (or for example - да ладно тебе грустить) - is "stop". i think, more deeply this "ладно" here mean reaching a good condition, limit, an ideal - like as just ладно = ok. See also "ладный, лад, ладить, ладушка" :)

Comment: ...что вы вообще ГОРОДИТЕ ? :> 
  ГОРОДИТЬ Разг. Говорить вздор, нелепости. Скорее, грубое просторечие. Выглядит не очень вежливо, учитывая, что мы  незнакомы.  Русский сленг   многозначен и не отражен в словарях в должной мере, но носители языка понимают  и могут объяснить значение. А вот подобрать англоговорящим людям правильное соответствие – задача не их простых. Здесь нужно хорошо понимать ситуацию и значение слова в русском языке, а на основе этих знаний найти для него  точный эквивалент. Такую задачу без  УВЕРЕННОГО НОСИТЕЛЯ  родного английского не решишь, а другим бы я не доверяла.

Comment: Вот я и говорю - что вы тут городите ? Требуя, чтобы англосаксы всякие объясняли сленг или еще там что - в русском, а не те, у кого русский родной язык. :))) Кстать, никаких "правильных соответствий в английском" тут подбирать не нужно (да и не всегда они существуют вообще) - а нужно просто объяснить. Бред какой-то.

Comment: "УВЕРЕННОГО НОСИТЕЛЯ" - а что сие ? Cправку генеалогическую имеющий, что он "носитель языка" ... или генекологическую... генекологически-лингвистическую... :> оральную, так сказать; или что... "уверенный носитель".... :> А неуверенный носитель - он каков ? Опишите.

Answer (score 0):

«Да ладно!» — this is the answer to the words of the interlocutor, with which the respondent strongly disagrees, so these words are pronounced with great emphasis. I think this is an abbreviated phrase *Да ладно тебе* (= *You don't need to, You shouldn't, don't have to* —  this is an old construction) *шутить!* (*= joke, be kidding!*). «Да ладно!» is a very good expression, I use it a lot myself :)

I remembered that there is an exclamation «Shoot!» аs an expression of surprise or disappointment in the English language, and this is also a suitable translation of «Да ладно!» (although the English expression is clearly not a reference to an old speech, but simply a more socially acceptable replacement for the exclamation «Shit!»).

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, здесь можно обозначить два варианта.

1. *Да ладно!*  (Ладно ли, правда ли это?)  Это удивление, недоверие к словам собеседника, иногда действительное (не может быть!), а иногда ироническое (хорош сочинять!).
2. *Да ладно тебе!*  (Хватит, достаточно тебе что-либо делать). Здесь спектр значений самый широкий и зависит от ситуации: хватит сочинять, прикидываться, расстраиваться, обижаться, благодарить и т.д.

Перевод:

It seems to me that there are two options here.

Come on! (Is this exactly the case? Is it true?) This is surprise, distrust of the words of the interlocutor. Sometimes real (it can't be!), and sometimes ironic (it's good to compose!).

Oh, come on! (That's enough, it's enough for you to do something). Here the range of meanings is the widest and depends on the situation: stop composing, pretending, getting upset, being offended, thanking, etc.

Comment: «Oh, come on! (That's enough, it's enough for you to do something)» — :))) Google translator is a very unreliable tool.

Comment: @Егор Сальков   https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/24721/origin-of-expression-%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be